# Testing | Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined at resetFakeAsyncZone

Tags: angular, testing, karma-runner, zone.js

I have a problem with karma v1.4. testing framework. 
All my unit tests are now failing with error `Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined at resetFakeAsyncZone`

I've already searched for solutions and tested them, but unfortunately none helped.
The solutions suggests that I should change the order of imports in my test.js file. I've done that.

This is the suggested order I am using, but it still fails:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js'; // 1st
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test'; // 2nd
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test'; // 3rd
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone'; // 4th
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test'; // 5th
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js'; // 6th
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch'; // 7th
```

PS: I am using VS Code, which now automatically sorts imports upon file save and thus changes my custom order of imports, which is super annoying in this case. I do not know how to disable it for specific file only, so I have to edit my test.js file in Notepad.

Answer (score 32):

Which version of `zone.js` is used?

In the newer version of `zone.js`, there is no need to load each *test lib* separately.

Place the following at the top of `test.ts`.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
```

Note: It is important that this import is before any other imports!

Comment: I am using version 0.8.26, but that import did not change anything. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Could you provide a reproduce repo?

Comment: Had the same problem with the same zone version. Solution was not to reorder imports in test.ts: Put `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';` before every other import.

Comment: @MrCube Thanks for pointing this out. Implementing tslint --fix with alphabatized imports rule will introduce this issue for the exact reason you point out!

Comment: "at the top" is really important

Comment: To be absolutely clear, it should be before any other imports, *except* your existing polyfills, which is where most of us put the core `zone.js/dist/zone`.  `zone-testing` needs to have `zone` loaded first.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this problem after VS Code re-ordered my imports.

The fix is to include the 2 zone imports first - I'm adding a new answer b/c `zone-testing` needs to come after `zone`. (If you put `zone-testing` before `zone`, you'll get a `Zone is not defined in ..../vendor.js` error).

Here is the full code for a working `test.ts` file:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing'; // AFTER zone, BEFORE everything else

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';


declare const require: {
  context(path: string, deep?: boolean, filter?: RegExp): {
    keys(): string[];
    <T>(id: string): T;
  };
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('../../', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the order and you can add this:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:ordered-imports
```

to disable import order for the next line

```
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
// tslint:disable-next-line:ordered-imports
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
// tslint:disable-next-line:ordered-imports
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
```

or disable it for the block

```
// tslint:disable:ordered-imports
 import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
 import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
 import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
 import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
 import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
 import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
```

and run your test like this to see the exact error:

```
ng test -sm=false
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still fails with the same error. I have upgraded the npm packages related to unit testing to their latest versions, but it did not help.

Comment: run your test like this to see the exact error : ng test -sm=false

Answer (score 1):

Best Solution is to use `jasmine clock`

```
it('test', () => {
  // arrange
  const clock = jasmine.clock();
  clock.install();
  ... other arrangements

  // act
  ... actions
  clock.tick(2000);

  // assert
  clock.uninstall();
  ... asserts
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when a Jasmine test was using fakeAsync and tick. Removing fakeAsync/tick resolved this issue.

Comment: Why was it there in the first place?

Comment: This worked for me, not sure why you get all these downs

Comment: what if I need the fakeasync + tick?

Comment: setTimeout in the code being tested can cause this issue. Try using flush() or tick(<millis>).