# error using fakeasync - but it works elsewhere

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a mind-boggling issue. I have some code I am testing in two different projects, both in angular. In the first project, the tests work, in the second I get the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983015/testing-cannot-read-property-assertpresent-of-undefined-at-resetfakeasynczon) about the issue, but all solutions they discuss importing `zone.js` and the order etc. However, in neither my working test project nor my non-working one, I do not explicitly import `zone.js`.

The testing code tests http with a delay, so it needs `fakeAsync` to use `tick`. This is the test that tests the codes in both projects:

```
it('should throw error if action failed`, fakeAsync(()=>{
    const mockGetActionResponse = {'action' : {'id' : mockActionId, state: 'Failed' }};
    
    service.doAction(mockContent).subscribe(
        () => {},
        err => expect(err).toEqual('Action Failed');
    );

    const postCall = httpTestingController.expectOne(url1);
    expect(postCall.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    expect(postCall.request.body).toEqual(mockContent);

    postCall.flush(mockPostActionResponse);

    tick(config.retryTime);

    const getCall = httpTestingController.expectOne(url2/mockActionId);
    expect(getCall .request.method).toEqual('Get');

    getCall.flush(mockGetActionResponse );
}));
```

Now in project 1, it works perfectly, and in project 2 I get the aforementioned error. I have the same imports in both:

```
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {fakeAsync, TestBed, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
```

in my `package.json` `devDependencies` I have the following similarities: (removed quotes here for ease)

```
jasmine-core: 3.6.0,
jasmine-spec-reporter: 6.0.0,
karma: 5.2.3 (p1) / ^5.2.3 (p2)
karma-jasmine: 4.1.0,
karma-jasmine-html-reporter: 1.5.4
```

Now, in p2 I updated karma-coverage to no longer use `instabul`, and p1 uses electron where as p2 does not, so now I have the following differences too:

```
karma-coverage-instabul-reporter: 3.0.3, // P1 only
karma-coverage: ^2.0.3, // p2 only
karma-electron: 6.3.1, // p1 only
karma-chrome-launcher: ~3.1.0 // p2 only 
karma-junit-reporter: ^2.0.1 //p2 only
```

similar regular dependency: `zone.js: 0.11.1 (p1) / ^0.11.2 (p2)`

The other major difference perhaps worth noting is that p1 is angular 10, where as p2 is angular 11.
Again, the code is the same, as is the test, so I am having a really hard time understanding why in p2 I get the aforementioned error.

Any leads would be greatly apprectiated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/232#issuecomment-474633034) on a github post, I discovered that P1 had an import p2 lacked.

In `test.ts`, the file that is required by `karma.conf.js` and is responsible for recursively loading all the spec files, there was an import missing. Adding it to p2's `test.ts` solved the issue.

`import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';`